# 2D array of buttons in Android

Tags: android, button, multidimensional-array, android-widget, android-layout

I want to create a 2D array of buttons for a basic game that involves a grid of buttons. Does anyone know how to do this with the buttons aligning nicely? I can create Button objects but can't align them so it looks like a nice grid.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a GridView.  Here's an example of it:

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html